# Represent the same item twice in a D3 visualisation

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

The effect I'm going for in a map based visualisation is:

- Red circles on a map represent data (things at locations)
- When something happens at a location, we briefly (2 seconds) show another, blue circle fading out over the top.

I'm trying to work out how to do this in the D3 paradigm. Specifically: how do you represent the same thing twice?

The problem I run into is that when I try to add the same dataset twice to a given SVG canvas group, nothing gets added. That is, using code like this:

```
g = svg.append("g");

var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(stations)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .style("opacity", .6) 
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("r", function(d, i) { return d.free_bikes; });  

var emphasis = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(stations)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .style("opacity", .6) 
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("r", function(d, i) { return d.free_bikes; });
```

This workaround is ok, but kludgy and potentially limiting:

```
g2 = svg.append("g");
var emphasis = g2.selectAll("circle")
```

That is, adding the second group of elements to a different SVG group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use classes to select the circles (and applying that class when you create them). So you create the features like so:

```
var feature = g.selectAll("circle.feature")
  .data(stations, function (d) { return d.id; } )
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "feature") // <- assign the class
  ....
```

Similarly, for the emphasis:

```
var feature = g.selectAll("circle.emphasis")
  .data(stations, function (d) { return d.id; } )
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "emphasis") // <- assign the class
  ....
```

Comment: Sweet, that's the last bit I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally (sort of) figured it out. The two sets of data are treated as one because they share the same key, according to the rules of [D3 constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). So an easy way around is to give each set a key that can't overlap:

```
var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(stations, function (d) { return d.id; } )
  .enter().append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .style("opacity", .6) 
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("r", function(d, i) { return d.free_bikes * 1; });  

var emphasis = g.selectAll("notathing")
  .data(stations, function (d) { return d.id + " cannot possibly overlap"; } )
  .enter().append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .style("opacity", .6) 
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("r", function(d, i) { return d.free_bikes * 1; });
```

The only slight quirk is I have to modify the second selector (`g.selectAll("notathing")`) so it doesn't match any of the circles created by the first one.

Comment: thank you so much!! this solution best fit my problem!!! but how come "notathing" work, unbelievable